# Save state of activity

Tags: android, save, state

I'm trying to save and restore state of activity in my app.
I don't want to save it when it's closed, but when it is paused (going to another activity, etc.) It behaves like that, when I press the home button, but it's default.
when I click on ListView item and get back to my activity I would like my app to:

-show the items again with no need to recreate it again
-show the last position of ListView (int)

I am using an ArrayList of custom objects - ArrayList

Could you please advice me which method is the best to use in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is built into the activity and fragment lifecycle as *instance states*:

[image: Illustration of instance states]

You can save the instance state using `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` where you add items into a Bundle.

Similarly, you can read this instance state in `Activity.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

I strongly encourage you [to read the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).